# How can I reduce amount of graphics to draw for a smooth 2D character evolution transition?

Tags: 2d, animation, graphics

I'm working on a game where the player has a character that can be fatter or skinnier, and maybe other transitions. Not only the height and width could change, but the complete appearance of the body.

I'm using separately the body parts for animations, and I can handle the animation transition pretty well.

I was thinking about drawing all the graphics to make nice and smooth transitions, but for example if the character has 20 states, and it has minimum 8 parts/state, I have to draw 160 graphics. It seems too much for me.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of work to have all of these states? I'm open to completely different techniques too.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.se! I reworded to something more precise, "best way" being too broad.

Comment: Could you include some sample images of what a few of these states look like, and how you want the transitions between them to look? Depending on the visual result you want, different techniques might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an explosion over everything you want to hide.

Comment: Though glib, this is actually a very viable and frequently-used technique in games. A little particle effect showmanship can hide a wide array of asset-popping sins. ;) I'd say it's an option worth considering, especially if this answer could be elaborated on with some more detail about a recommended transition-hiding effect style and how to achieve it.